# Upload Image to Twitter

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, hammock

I am trying to upload an image to Twitter using Twitter API Version 1.1 and the update_with_media.json method.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

This is the code I have so far, yet despite numerous variations I can not get a successful upload.

```
    public TwitterResponse UpdateStatus(string message, String fileName, String contentType, byte[] image)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = TwitterConstants.Authority,
            VersionPath = TwitterConstants.Version

        };

        message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message);

        client.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");

        client.AddField("status", message);
        client.AddField("media[]", Convert.ToBase64String(image) + ";filename=" + fileName + ";type=" + contentType);

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = this.Credentials,
            Path = "statuses/update_with_media.json",
            Method = Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post

        };

        return new TwitterResponse(client.Request(request));
    }
```

I am using Hammock to perform these requests.

Just to rule out possible other issues, I can successfully post a status update to Twitter using the update.json method.

I have also tried using the client.AddFile method and using Fiddler it looks like everything is in place. But the error message I keep getting back is

```
{"errors":[{"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter"}]}
```

Comment: I'm so sad to see `update_with_media.json` is depreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using native Twitter API, you can use TweeterSharp plugin available at Nuget.

Sample with description is written at this article by me [Post message with image on twitter using C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3196/post-message-with-image-on-twitter-using-csharp)

In particular this is the code snippet

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var result = service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
                {
                    Status = message,
                    Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "john", stream } }
                });
                lblResult.Text = result.Text.ToString();
            }
```

The complete demo is downloadable attached with the article, feel free to download.

Thanks

Comment: TweetSharp is what I used in the end on that project but it didn't come without its difficulties. Though that was 1.5 years ago now.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Hammock or or c#, but I know that we had a similar issue...

Our core twitter library worked for everything, but we couldn't get image uploads to work. It turns out that the OAuth library that our twitter lib depended on didn't calculate the signature properly when posting files. We had to update our oauth to get it work.

In our case the exact code we were trying to use worked fine once I substituted an updated OAuth.

If you are using an older version of OAuth, I would suggest looking for a more recent version, and pulling together a quick script to try with that.

Regarding that error message, it may be more of a red herring than a valid message - especially because it's not even listed on their error page:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses